# Looking for an error in a fairly basic C++ program I've written which deals with csv files

Tags: c++, csv, struct

Can't seem to figure out why exactly this program won't work. It is supposed to store data from a csv file into a structure called SurnameInfo (when used with a loop that iterates through each line) but whenever I run it it gets to line 1280 of 151671 of the csv file, crashes, and gives the windows "program.exe has stopped working" popup. Anyone see anything that might cause this? Thanks!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

const int MAXLINE = 1000;
const int MAXARRAY = 1000;
int numberOfNames;

struct SurnameInfo
{
    char *name;
    int count;
    float pctrace[6];
};
SurnameInfo*surnames[MAXARRAY];

void processLine(char *line, int n)
{
    surnames[n] = new SurnameInfo; //allocate memory
    char * pch = strtok(line, ",");//start tokenizing
    int len = strlen(pch); // name length
    surnames[n]->name = new char[len+1]; //allocate memory
    strcpy(surnames[n]->name, pch); // copy name
    surnames[n]->count = atoi(strtok(NULL, ","));//get count
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        pch = strtok(NULL, ",");
        surnames[n]->pctrace[i] = pch[0] == '(' ? -1 : atof(pch);
    }
}

void readLines()
{
    char line[MAXLINE];
    ifstream inputfile;
    inputfile.open("names.csv");
    if (!inputfile) return; // can't open
    inputfile.getline(line, MAXLINE); //skip title
    inputfile.getline(line, MAXLINE);
    numberOfNames = 0;
    while (!inputfile.eof()) //not end of file
    {
        processLine(line, numberOfNames++);
        inputfile.getline(line, MAXLINE);
    }
    inputfile.close();
}

int main() {
readLines();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried finding the exact error? Catching exceptions, checking event log, etc?

Comment: Try running it in the debugger.

Comment: horrible code. Please use std::string instead of char*.

Comment: You said there are 151671 lines in the CSV file. Your per-line array  of structure pointers is only 1000 elements long (`SurnameInfo*surnames[MAXARRAY];`, where you declare `const int MAXARRAY = 1000;`). I'm surprised it made it to 1280 before it finally bit the dust. that's 280 more pointers than you have space for.

Comment: The code is for a class I am taking and these functions were given to us by a professor. So I have to use char* but as I am very new to c++ I didn't really know any better anyway.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a discrepancy in the code and the stuff that you are talking. 
`const int MAXARRAY = 1000;` && `SurnameInfo*surnames[MAXARRAY];` goes against `151671 of the csv file`.

You are allocating 1000 and trying to push more to the heap unattended which means it starts eating the memory allocated to the program itself. Or it tries to access the area which it is not supposed to (may be program area of some other process is allocated), and thus pushes out a `Segmentation Fault`

Also, you need to have a way to destruct the `Surnames` that are dynamically fed.

My Suggestion :

`Approach 1 :` Read through the file first and get the number of lines. Allocate the respective memory to `Surnames` and proceed the way you are.
Though it requires one additional scan of file, but would solve your purpose. Time complexity goes very high if the file size is high.(May be you can cache stuff while reading , use vector?? (think on that))

`Approach 2 :` Implement a functionality similar to resize of vector.On every new addition to the `Surnames`, Free the previously allocated memory on heap and reallocate with the higher memory spec by deep copying and inserting new info.

Also,

```
surnames[n]->pctrace[i] = pch[0] == '(' ? -1 : atof(pch);
```

I am not very sure whether this would work correctly or not. Just for the sake of safety and more clear code, put that up in parenthesis . Something like this

```
surnames[n]->pctrace[i] = ((pch[0] == '(') ? -1 : atof(pch));
```

If this is your one of the first attempts on C++, this is nicely done. Cheers.

Hope the answer helps.

Comment: Thank You! I hadn't noticed the MAX_ARRAY discrepancy. Also I appreciate the suggestions! I'll see if I can implement them.

Comment: yep. Use a string in place of char* (think about it)

Comment: Also use vector<SurnameInfo> (think bout it)

Comment: @mtihlenfield : If this helped u in reaching the solution, up it if u want to.

Comment: Just joined stack overflow so I don't have enough reputation to upvote yet.

Comment: Its okay, Ideally i should not ask you to do so. I am being greedy lol. Nevertheless, I am glad it helped you :)